# Including Jersey for ResourceConfig in Netbeans 8 with Glassfish 4

Tags: java, glassfish, jersey, jax-rs

As per described here: https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/user-guide.html#servlet-app-glassfish Glassfish is supposed to come packaged with Jersey. However, ResourceConfig is not included in the classpath. If I try to manually add it to the project through "Add Libraries", I receive the following error:

```
SEVERE:   Exception during lifecycle processing org.glassfish.deployment.common.DeploymentException: CDI deployment failure:WELD-001408 Unsatisfied dependencies for type [IterableProvider<InjectionResolver<Object>>] with qualifiers [@Default] at injection point [[BackedAnnotatedParameter] Parameter 2 of [BackedAnnotatedConstructor] @Inject org.glassfish.jersey.internal.inject.JerseyClassAnalyzer(@Named ClassAnalyzer, IterableProvider<InjectionResolver<Object>>)]
at org.glassfish.weld.WeldDeployer.event(WeldDeployer.java:225)
at org.glassfish.kernel.event.EventsImpl.send(EventsImpl.java:131)
at org.glassfish.internal.data.ApplicationInfo.load(ApplicationInfo.java:328)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:493)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:219)
at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.execute(DeployCommand.java:491)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:537)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:546)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1423)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$1500(CommandRunnerImpl.java:108)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1762)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1674)
at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.ReDeployCommand.execute(ReDeployCommand.java:131)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:527)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:523)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:356)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:522)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:546)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1423)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$1500(CommandRunnerImpl.java:108)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1762)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1674)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.doCommand(AdminAdapter.java:534)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.onMissingResource(AdminAdapter.java:224)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.StaticHttpHandler.service(StaticHttpHandler.java:297)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:246)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:191)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:168)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:189)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:288)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:206)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:136)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:114)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:838)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:113)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:115)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:55)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:135)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:564)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:544)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724) Caused by: org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DeploymentException: WELD-001408 Unsatisfied dependencies for type [IterableProvider<InjectionResolver<Object>>] with qualifiers [@Default] at injection point [[BackedAnnotatedParameter] Parameter 2 of [BackedAnnotatedConstructor] @Inject org.glassfish.jersey.internal.inject.JerseyClassAnalyzer(@Named ClassAnalyzer, IterableProvider<InjectionResolver<Object>>)]
at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateInjectionPointForDeploymentProblems(Validator.java:403)
at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateInjectionPoint(Validator.java:325)
at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateGeneralBean(Validator.java:177)
at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateRIBean(Validator.java:208)
at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateBean(Validator.java:519)
at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateBeans(Validator.java:505)
at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateDeployment(Validator.java:480)
at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.WeldBootstrap.validateBeans(WeldBootstrap.java:536)
at org.glassfish.weld.WeldDeployer.event(WeldDeployer.java:216)
... 43 more
```

Any idea on what this error means, how to fix it, and get ResourceConfig available for usage in my RESTful project?

Comment: `ResourceConfig` is definitely in GF 4. What's the error before add the library to your project?

Comment: @Michal cannot find symbol
public class ExampleApp extends ResourceConfig {
  symbol: class ResourceConfig

Comment: You import `org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig`, right? The exception you see is in NetBeans or directly in GF?

Comment: That's correct. for a more specific error: http://pastebin.com/SRSR4DnF

Comment: Can you mark the added library as "provided" in Netbeans? If you created pure JAX-RS project in NB then it's likely that the IDE doesn't see Jersey classes but needs them to compile the project AND you don't want to add the library to resulting war (as it's already in GF).

Comment: Michal, this did it. If you'd like to post the solution, I'll mark you as correct, otherwise I can post it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you create a pure JAX-RS project in NetBean then you have only JAX-RS 2.0 APIs available in your application. If you want to use specific features of Jersey and deploy your application  to GlassFish you need to add Jersey bits to the project manually and mark them as "provided". This way the compiler will see the classes but they're not bundled into resulting WAR (as they're already part of GF).